# ASP.NET MVC losing controller variable data

Tags: c#, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am working with .NET Core MVC and I'm running into an issue. The temp variable below losses its data. When running the Index action, the temp variable holds and stores the data normally, when I call the GetOptions action, it shows that its null.

```cs
private List<tempObject> temp;

public IActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, FilterOptions filterOptions)
{
    temp = spAccessLayer.GetTempOptions(filterOptions, UserProfile.GetID());

    return View();
}

public IActionResult GetOptions()
{
    return Json(temp);
}
```

Comment: you can use the TempData https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controller.tempdata?view=aspnetcore-2.0

Comment: Every time ASP.Net receives a request, it creates a new controller to process that request.  The controller is not re-used.  Values you set in private fields will be lost once that request processing pipeline has concluded.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5939353/how-do-you-keep-the-value-of-global-variables-between-different-action-methods-c

Answer (score 2):

HTTP, and consequently MVC, is stateless, or in other words, data is not persisted between requests.

.NET has ways of mimicking state; you can use `TempData` or `Session` depending on your requirements.

`TempData` will persist across 1 HTTP request before being cleared, whereas `Session` will be persisted for an entire user session.

An example using `TempData`:

```
private IEnumerable<tempObject> temp
{
    get => TempData["temp"] as IEnumerable<tempObject>;
    set => TempData["temp"] = value;
}
```

The other way would be to pass your list to your view, then use hidden fields to post back to your controller.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to reset it for each individual request. The Get request for Index is different from the get request for GetOptions.

```
private List<tempObject> temp;

public IActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, FilterOptions filterOptions)
{
    temp = spAccessLayer.GetTempOptions(filterOptions, UserProfile.GetID());

    return View();
}

public IActionResult GetOptions()
{
    temp = spAccessLayer.GetTempOptions(filterOptions, UserProfile.GetID());
    return Json(temp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpcontext.session?view=netframework-4.8) to store data across requests. Something akin to this:

```
public IActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request, FilterOptions filterOptions)
{
    Session[someKey] = spAccessLayer.GetTempOptions(filterOptions, UserProfile.GetID());

    return View();
}

public IActionResult GetOptions()
{
    return Json(Session[someKey]);
}
```

The distinction though is that you'll need to keep track of `someKey`, which is just a unique string that you provide. Session is sort of like `Dictionary<string, object>` in basic usage, for frame of reference.